# Remove the Standard callout from MapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I need to remove the Standard Callout from the mapview and want to display my custom callout. My custom Callout is having image and many fields. I am designing my custom callout in interface builder. 
How I can display my custom callout ?

I have referred to the link "Custom callout Bubble", But I want to display the custom callout from xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom callouts are nearly impossible to implement. You have to simulate a callout by adding your own custom MKAnnotationView to your MKAnnotations, listen to their selection, then listen to your MKANnotationView's didMoveToSuperView callbacks to handle your own animations and drawing.

[My implementation on the iPad](http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/109/Purple/d6/b7/fb/mzl.papsfirm.480x480-75.jpg) took weeks to get right and if I were to do it again I wouldn't use Apple's MapKit at all. I'd use another mapping framework altogether that made the process easier.

**tldr  - you can't do it**  - *trust me*

Answer (score 2):

It's not simple, but you can do it.
You need to create an alternative MKAnnotationView (BubbleView) and show it when you select the first one.
It's possible to differentiate the AnnotationView from BubbleView in delegate.

You have a lot of work to do, this tutorial can help you to understand the passages, but pay attention on iOS 6, some things are changed and there are some problems in BubbleView positioning

http://www.jakeri.net/2009/12/custom-callout-bubble-in-mkmapview-final-solution/